# Detaching entities when using RepositoryPattern with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity, repository-pattern

Lets say i have a ITaskRepository and a TaskEntityRepository that implements the ITaskRepository and wraps the access to the ObjectContext of the Entity.

```
public interface ITaskRepository{
  Task FindById(int taskId);
  void Insert(Task task);
  void Update(Task task);
}
```

My question is now should i detach the entities from the ObjectContext when it gets returned by FindById and attach it back when the method Update is called?

Currently i don´t detach the entities from the ObjectContext, but then the Update-method contains no functionality (only calls SaveChanges())

Comment: If you are working in a stateful environment (winforms, wpf, single reqeuest processing) there should be no reason to detach entity. If you are working in stateless environment (asp.net, asp.net mvc, multile related requests processing) follow @RPM advice. It is hard to help you better because your question is missing infomration like: What type of application are you building? Are you using POCOs, STEs or heavy EF Entities? How do yo handle ObjectContext? etc.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Sorry for the missing pieces. I will add more information later. Its a Siverlight 4 / WCF RIA Services / EF 4 application without poco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your application.

If your working in a *stateless environment* (e.g ASP.NET Web Forms / MVC), then the entire context is always detached (unless your using self-tracking POCO's).

So, taking the example of an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, you've got two options when you want to make changes to an existing entity:

1. Go get the entity again (using `FindById`), then use `Controller.TryUpdateModel` to merge in the changes, then do `SaveChanges()`. In this scenario, your `Update` method is not required. You should change it to simply `SaveChanges()`.
2. Don't get the entity, instead use your `Update` method to `Attach` the entity to the graph, and make your changes manually.

2) Is a pain with POCO's (trust me). `ApplCurrentValues` only works for scalar properties, so if you want to update relationshships, you'll have to manually set the `EntityState` for each relationship.

My advice - forget detaching entities, and lose your `Update` method altogether.

As i said though - depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the Database design first and them create your entities from the database then there is no way to separate entities from the ObjectContext. However, you can choose the code first POCO model and then create DbContext separately, then you should be able to separate entities from the underlying context.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "separate entities"? The POCO model is no option for me.